# Regex to match substring containing 18 digits but don't match if it starts with @

Tags: javascript, regex

I've looked for a solution and played around a bit with some examples but couldn't find what I'm looking for. (I'm using javascript)

Basically it should only match a string of 18 digits if the first character isn't `@`, it should only include the 18 digits.

So something like `/[^@]\d{18}/g` but if I do this it includes the first character that is not an `@`

Examples: `test 123456789012345678 abc` match `123456789012345678`

`test @123456789012345678 abc` don't match.

Comment: use look behind `/(?<!@)\d{18}/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to match an @ and a digit that you don't want, and then capture 18 digits between word boundaries `\b` in capture group 1 that you want to keep.

The word boundaries are to prevent a partial match for the digits.

```
@\d|\b(\d{18})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TrQjwc/1)

If supported, you can also use a negative lookbehind:

```
\b(?<!@)\d{18}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vhlNl8/1)